# Formatting date output with Advanced custom fields in wordpress

Tags: wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

I am struggling to get the date to output (at all!)

I have the following and I want the date to be output like 26th May 2014

```
            <p><?php the_field('description'); ?></p>
        <?php $date = DateTime::createFromFormat('Ymd', get_field('when')); ?>
        <h2><?php echo $date->format('d-m-Y'); ?></p>
```

All the above is inside a wordpress loop
Even if I move the variable declaration outside the loop, it still doesn;t work.

thanks

Answer (score 0):

This will echo:

```
<?php the_date('jS F Y'); ?>
```

This will return the value to the `$date` var:

```
<?php $date = get_the_date('jS F Y'); ?>
```